# Generate report for every week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the report on weekly basis to know the status of how many were actually using the product.

This is my current query

```
select 
COUNT(*) as 'TotalPurchased',
SUM(case when date<= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'week1' 
from #myreport
```

I wanted the output as

```
Totalpurchased   week1  week2 week3 ..........so on
  82              80     14    16
```

It should go upto year end.

I'm getting the output for only one week from the above query. I'm fetching the data from the temporary table with sql 2008 r2 environment.

Comment: You want it to always start with week 1 as the most recent week?  Should it always go 52 weeks back, or to the beginning of the calendar year?

Comment: I wanted to start from 01-05-2013 and it should go to 01-05-2014.

Comment: So why didn't you just add more weeks to you select clause? e.g. `SUM(case when date<= DATEADD(day, -14, GETDATE()) AND date > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'week2' `

Comment: Then I have to add 52 entries like that which is not a feasible solution

Comment: You should use tally table to enumerate weeks, convert that to datetime, aggregate existing data and finally pivot that. If there isn't elegant solution in half an hour I will provide one.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Why don't you post your elegant answer now instead of belittle other answers (and users)?

Comment: Because at the moment I saw this Q&A thread I had to go wash and feed my children, but everything seemed a bit too ugly. Now i took a few minutes to read it seems that only one question is ugly and that is variable number of columns.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić The variable number of columns is part of the question, and had a good answer. I don't get why you would say that *If there isn't elegant solution in half an hour I will provide one*

Comment: @user2459816: do you really need variable number of columns? Variable number of output columns can be the source of the SQL server expression problems.

Comment: *‘I wanted to start from 01-05-2013 and it should go to 01-05-2014’* – Well, first of all, is it the 1st of May of the 5th of January? At first I considered it to be the former, but thought it wouldn't hurt to verify. Next question is, should `01-05-2013` also be the beginning of the week (or should I say 7-day period)? Also, since the number of days between those two dates is 365, which is 7×52+1, would you need to have an incomplete (1-day) week (as `week53` probably) or should the range instead be adjusted to 364 days (exactly 52 full weeks)?

Answer (score 8):

You can use dynamic sql and `PIVOT` to do this if you're bent on returning columns:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(8000),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +   QUOTENAME(YrWeek) 
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(YEAR(rpt_dt)AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(week,rpt_dt)AS VARCHAR(2))'YrWeek'
                          FROM #myreport
                          WHERE rpt_dt > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()))sub
                    ORDER BY LEFT(YrWeek,4) DESC,RIGHT(YrWeek,2)DESC
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
                (
                SELECT CAST(YEAR(rpt_dt)AS VARCHAR(4)) + ''-'' + CAST(DATEPART(week,rpt_dt)AS VARCHAR(2)) YrWeek, COUNT(*)CT
                FROM #myreport   
                GROUP BY CAST(YEAR(rpt_dt)AS VARCHAR(4)) + ''-'' + CAST(DATEPART(week,rpt_dt)AS VARCHAR(2))
                ) AS T1
                PIVOT (SUM(CT) FOR YrWeek IN ('+@cols+')) AS T2

'
EXEC(@query)
```

In this example it's pulling every week in the last year, from today backward.

Here's a demo, using just a list of dates and taking a count of records by that date, which I think is the same as what you're ultimately doing.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a034/2/0)

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Well, dynamic pivot queries aren't the simplest, but I don't think there's a simpler query that would produce the desired output.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Unfortunately, if the OP wants to return a unknown number of column this has to be done using dynamic SQL and this is the correct way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (you may have to adjust the date range as you need it):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS 'count',
    CONVERT(nchar(4), DATEPART(year, [date]))
     + '-' + 
    CONVERT(nchar(2), DATEPART(wk, [date])) AS 'week'
FROM #myreport
WHERE
    [date] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(week, 52, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(nchar(4), DATEPART(year, [date]))
     + '-' + 
    CONVERT(nchar(2), DATEPART(wk, [date]))
WITH ROLLUP
```

The data is returned in rows rather than columns. Database queries work this way and it is highly impractical to try and force the data into dynamic columns. You can only resort to what Conrad said, or use dynamic sql (building a string with a while-loop) to do the same. I would not do that.

`WITH ROLLUP` will simply add another row with 'Week' = NULL and the total sum as 'Count'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for weekly report

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR((DATEDIFF(DAY, 'YourStartDate', [DateColumn])) / 7) + 1 AS [Week], 
    CAST(CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, FLOOR((DATEDIFF(DAY, 'YourStartData', [DateColumn])) / 7), 'YourStartData') AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR(16)) + ' - ' + 
    CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, FLOOR((DATEDIFF(DAY, 'YourStartData', [DateColumn])) / 7) * 7 + 6, 'YourStartData') AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR(16)) AS [Range], 
    COUNT(*) AS [TotalPurchased] 
FROM 
    [Table] WITH (NOLOCK) 
GROUP BY 
    FLOOR((DATEDIFF(DAY, 'YourStartDate', [DateColumn])) / 7) 
ORDER BY 
    FLOOR((DATEDIFF(DAY, 'YourStartDate', [DateColumn])) / 7) + 1
```

Result will show you: 
week number, range (from YourStartDate - up to 7 days) and TotalPurchased. You can also use CAST(GETDATE() as date) as a parameter instead of 'YourStartDate'

Answer (score 0):

This is just another solution that you can tailor as you wish.

Note that there isn't a variable set of columns. Maybe you should re-question your requirements. Returning a result with variable set of columns will not just mess with your execution plan caching, it can represent a problem to your database mapping in application that needs that result.

Well, here it goes...

```
DECLARE @start datetime = '2012-6-1'

;WITH tally AS (
  SELECT TOP 52 -- change this if you want more or less than a year of data
    N = row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1
  FROM master.dbo.syscolumns sc1)
,weekSums AS (
  SELECT 
    N,
    val = 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) -- Can be ISNULL(SUM(amount), 0) or something else
      FROM #myreport
      WHERE [date] > DATEADD(dd, N * 7, @start) AND at <= DATEADD(dd, (N + 1) * 7, @start))
  FROM tally)
SELECT
  totalPurchased = (SELECT sum(val) FROM weekSums),
  week1 = (SELECT val FROM weekSums WHERE N = 0),
  week2 = (SELECT val FROM weekSums WHERE N = 1),
  week3 = (SELECT val FROM weekSums WHERE N = 2),
  ...
  week52 = (SELECT val FROM weekSums WHERE N = 51)
```

You can see tally for week numbering, weekSums for summing it up and final select to show the results. It is fast, execution plan can be saved and reused (e.g. when wrapped in SP).

**NOTE**: This script CAN be finished with dynamic coalescing/stuffing but I don't support that kind of approach if not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @downvoters: downvoting a correct, documented and working answer without a comment can be a sign of ignorance or maliciousness. Feel free to argument what is wrong here.